# Добавление модели в ImageTarget через код

Tags: unity3d-android, unity3d, unity3d-editor, vuforia

Как можно добавить префаб/модель в ImageTarget ***через код***? (речь идёт про Vuforia и Unity)
Пробовал данный способ:

```
model = Instantiate(obj, obj.transform.position, 
            obj.transform.rotation, GameObject.Find("ImageTarget").transform);
```

Но он лишь выводил ошибку Trackable cart NO_POSE -- UNKNOWN. (cart картинка в ImageTarget)

Answer (score 0):

А зачем это делать через код? С плагином Вуфории картинки располагаются на сцене, а поверх располагаются 3д модели. Тут и кодить то не надо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я и так использую vuforia, просто для моей программы, это нужно делать через код